# Does every shockwave have an expansion wave behind it?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, non-linear-systems, shock-waves

Do all shockwaves have an expansion fan or expansion wave behind them? Does the air always expand behind a shockwave?

I assume that the strength of the expansion wave depends on the strength of the shockwave, and also the air has to be compressible.

Comment: You're thinking about a special class of shock waves, pressure waves in air, right? Because not all shock waves are. And, for example, behind the bow wave of a ship there is no expansion of air. ;)

Comment: @kricheli oh haha yes I’m talking about air shockwaves.